# Storing TIME vs DURATION as two separate types

Tags: postgresql, time, sqldatatypes, ansi-sql

Most databases have two separate data types to represent a `TIME` (range is 0 to 24h) and a `DURATION` where the range is much longer than that.

My questions is why is it necessary for there to be two different types here, and why can't it be handled more like a `VARCHAR` is done, that is, "time" would be something like `DURATION(24)` and "duration" might be something like `DURATION(24*7*365)`. What is the main reason that the two types need to be different as opposed to having something like a check/restraint on the domain or range of values it may have?

I believe `mysql` does not have a `duration` (just time), `postgres` has both, and `sqlserver` also does not have a `duration` type (again just a `time` and various other date/time's).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My questions is why is it necessary for there to be two different types here

Because they are two different things. A `time` is an absolute "moment during the day", e.g. "8 in the evening" or "3 in the morning".

An `interval` (=duration) is something like "2 months 3 days 10 hours 15 minutes and 42 seconds" - a value that cannot be represented as a `time`.

The `interval` type has another reason to exist: it can also correctly express the difference between two timestamps.

In theory anything you can express with a `time` value can be expressed with an `interval` as well. Actually a `timestamp` is also not necessary the, as every timestamp can also be expressed as an `interval` based on a start date you define.

But if you remove all types that "overlap" with other types, you would need to remove other types as well. `float` or `double` can always be expressed in a `numeric` value. In fact a `numeric` value can also be expressed as a really large integer value, so why keep the numeric.

The main reason to have different data types for different things is primarily efficiency and validation. But it also helps understanding your data model and improves expressiveness - if it's an `interval` you *know* by looking at the column's type that it represents a "duration", if it's a `time` column you *know* that it represents a "moment". And you see that without having to first consult the check constraints that are defined for the column.

Comment: @a -- thanks I made an edit on what I think was a typo in the second paragraph/sentence.